# How to recover emails in Outlook 2007

Tags: email, data-recovery, microsoft-outlook-2007

I lost emails in Outlook 2007 due a virus in Windows 7 Ultimate. I followed these steps:

1. Highlight the folder that originally contained the item.  (If you’re not sure which folder, than you have to repeat these steps for each possible folder).  In this example, we’ll restore something to the Inbox.
2. From the menu bar choose Tools –> Recover Deleted Items.  Keyboard shortcut (hold down ALT and press ‘t’ and then ‘t’ again).
3. A window will pop up with the most recently deleted items.
4. Highlight the message you want to restore and select the icon with a message with an arrow on top, ‘Recover Selected Items’.
5. To restore multiple messages, hold down ‘CTRL’ and select the items you want to restore

Unfourtunately these steps does not work for me. So, there is another way to recover my lost emails, i mean, a recovery tool or another thing, you know.

Comment: No; If what you attempted did not work it means the emails cannot be recovered.

Comment: It's really, this can't be, there must be some way. Thanks anyway for your reply.

Comment: There isn't another way.  If you wish to provide more information about the original configuration of your email client, despite already knowing there isn't a way to recover your emails, I will do some research.

Comment: Ok thank you, I will investigate further. If I  find the solution, I will comment.

Comment: What type of account do you use (Exchange/IMAP/POP3/...)?

Comment: What does lost emails mean? You lost ALL emails or SOME emails? Regardless, moving fowards, as of right now, take backs ups! If you had, you could have restored it.

Answer (score 1):

The way you've attempted will only work is you are using an Exchange account, and the Exchange server admin turned on Deleted Item Retention (on the server).

If you are using a POP3 mail account then the messages (most likely) only exist on your computer in a PST file. In which case you will need to restore a known-good PST from backup.

In that vein, here's some more information that you may find useful:

- [Where does Microsoft Office Outlook 2007 save my information and configurations?](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Where-does-Microsoft-Office-Outlook-2007-save-my-information-and-configurations-9d95ffe9-c1be-4012-b28f-7d5528c6690c)

Comment: Yes I'm using POP3, so I'll try to restore the PST file.
Thanks!

Comment: After  to I tried some recovery tools, I could recover my pst file with a tool called OutlookFIX and I've recovered my lost emails, not all, but the majority. Thanks for the support.